# Accessing variable inside of method loop without using an instance variable ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I access the player_1_symbol (and player_2_symbol) inside loop without setting it as an instance method. I'm trying to loop for any bad input, once it is out of the loop I'm going to call a new_method and need to pass the player_1_symbol.

```
  def select_player_symbol(player_1, player_2)
    loop do
      puts "What symbol would you like #{player_1} to be?"
      player_1_symbol = gets.chomp

      puts "What symbol would you like #{player_2} to be?"
      player_2_symbol = gets.chomp

      if player_2_symbol != player_1_symbol
        puts "player 1: #{player_1_symbol}"
        puts "player_2: #{player_2_symbol}"
        break
      end
      puts "Please pick different symbols for each player"
    end
    new_method{player_1,
               player_2,
               player_1_symbol, 
               player_2_symbol}" # How to access these last two variables
  end
```

This was my code beforehand but I wanted to refactor it. I'm not sure what the "more" proper way would be. But then I was really interested in knowing for the future if you had to call a variable outside of a loop how would you do it without setting it as an instance method.

```
  def select_player_symbol(player_1, player_2)
    puts "What symbol would you like #{player_1} to be?"
    player_1_symbol = gets.chomp

    puts "What symbol would you like #{player_2} to be?"
    player_2_symbol = gets.chomp

    while player_2_symbol == player_1_symbol
      puts "#{player_1} has already picked that symbol,"
      puts "please pick another symbol."
      player_2_symbol = gets.chomp
    end
    new_method{player_1,
               player_2,
               player_1_symbol, 
               player_2_symbol}
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set it before entering the loop like:

```
  def select_player_symbol(player_1, player_2)
    player_1_symbol = nil
    player_2_symbol = nil
    loop do
      ...
```

this works because with the suggested change the player_1_symbol is scoped at the method level. Before its scope was inside of the loop. When you left the loop you lost it.

Comment: Obviously correct, but perhaps OP would benefit from an explanation as to why this works.

Comment: added comment to clarify

Answer (score -2):

Define them outside of the method. 
Try it [HERE](https://repl.it/CDmj)

```
$player_1_symbol = nil
$player_2_symbol = nil


def select_player_symbol(player_1, player_2)
    loop do
      puts "What symbol would you like #{player_1} to be?"
      $player_1_symbol = gets.chomp

      puts "What symbol would you like #{player_2} to be?"
      $player_2_symbol = gets.chomp

      if $player_2_symbol != $player_1_symbol
        puts "player 1: #{$player_1_symbol}"
        puts "player 2: #{$player_2_symbol}"
        break
      end
      puts "Please pick different symbols for each player"
    end
end

def another_method()
   puts "Gloabals are still here #{$player_1_symbol} and #{$player_2_symbol}"

end

#lets try it 
 select_player_symbol("Joe","Adam")
 another_method()
```